# New items don't displaing in select-box from array factory use AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, factory, devextreme

Helloo, i created simple AngularJS application, i have two buttons(*Create New Phone* and *Create New Category*), i saved my *categories* into array use factory:

```
myApp.factory('categoriesStorage', function () {
    var storage = [];
    var categories = ["Apple","HTC"];

    storage.addCategory = function (categoryTest) {
        categories.push(categoryTest);
        console.log(categories);
    }

    storage.getCategories = function()
    {
        return categories;
    }

    return storage;
});
```

[image]

At *Add New Phone* form i have `dx-select-box` -element:

```
<div class="dx-label">Phone Name</div>
               <div dx-select-box="nameOfPhone" ng-model="phoneName"></div><br/><br />
```

For Getting elements from array i use the next code in my *HomeController.js*
//name of phone select-box pop-up

```
  $scope.nameOfPhone = {
        items: categoriesStorage.getCategories()

    };
```

It works[image]

till when i change focus or close *Add New Category* form, new elements adds into array but don't displaying into *select-box*.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Is there common controller between view adding category & phone?

Comment: Yes, one controller, two factories https://github.com/Ubuntus/DevExtremeAngularJSChartsTest/blob/master/DevExtremeAngularJSChartsTest/Controllers/Exercise/HomeController.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call this line again when Add phone view is displayed.

```
$scope.nameOfPhone = {
    items: categoriesStorage.getCategories()
};
```

Comment: i done like this:   *$scope.nameOfPhone.items = phonesAndCategoriesStorages.getCategories();* - nothing( may be do you have another ideas? source code of my app you can find https://github.com/Ubuntus/DevExtremeAngularJSChartsTest/blob/master/DevExtremeAngularJSChartsTest/Controllers/Exercise/HomeController.js

Comment: Not able to find proper view of the controller. Also, there is no other solution unless you store data on controller array of categories instead of saving to service since you have same controller. So whenever you update categories, controllers will have latest categories.  If above solution has solved your problem, please mark it as answer.